# Stackoverflow APIのv2.3はいつリリースされる?

Tags: 機能の要求, api

StackOverflowのAPIを使って、受信箱の未読の内容を取得し、通知するというアプリを作ろうとしています

受信箱の未読を取得するのは`/inbox/unread`を使えば簡単にできるのですが、1度取得した内容を既読にすることができません。

下の質問の回答によると、現在のAPI(v2.2)ではできず、次のバージョン(v2.3)でできるようになるとのことでした。

v2.3はいつリリースされるのでしょうか?

[feature request - Marking inbox items as read in api v2.2 - Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/questions/5059/marking-inbox-items-as-read-in-api-v2-2)